# loop overlay input video WITH SOUND ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I am attempting to overlay two videos using the following call to ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i los.mov -filter_complex \
   "[0:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=1280x720[top], [1:v]loop=-1:size=750, setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB, scale=1280x720, format=yuva420p, colorchannelmixer=aa=1[bottom],[top][bottom]overlay=shortest=1, format=yuv420p[out]"\ 
   -map "[out]" -map 1:a -b:v 2000k -r 29.97 out.mp4
```

I want the videos to be overlaid *and* for the sound of both videos to play but with the above only audio from one of the videos can be heard.

Comment: Use amix or amerge filters.

Comment: @llogan
it is don't work :( 

Too many inputs specified for the "amix" filter.

Comment: The amerge and amix filter cannot work. Sound is played only once. But you need to always play when the video appears (endlessly)

Comment: I missed the `loop`. Use amix then add aloop. Can't make any suggestions about `Too many inputs specified for the "amix" filter.` without your command and log.

Comment: Share full log. Generally, it is better to use -stream_loop for the input rather than the loop filter.

Comment: @llogan pls help me for money

Comment: @РоманДэффи Consider asking Gyan. He does FFmpeg consulting/contracting.

Comment: I started using the command "-stream_loop"
And I managed to do what I want. Nearly....
Now he imposes everything endlessly (he must stop himself). How to make it stop when the video.mp4 video ends.
For example, if you put "-stream_loop" before the command "-i video.mp4", then it makes a video 15 seconds long (los.mov lasts 15 seconds), and if you put it as I need, the video is endless

Comment: ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -stream_loop -1 -i los.mov -filter_complex "[0:a][1:a]amix[out],[0:v][1:v]overlay=shortest=1" -map [out] -map 1:a -shortest out.mp4


If you make a command like this, then the video has a normal length, but there is not enough sound from the second video

"ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -stream_loop -1 -i los.mov -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=shortest=1" -map 0:a -map 1:a -shortest out.mp4"

Comment: Hurrah! I did it